# AsyncEnumerator not waiting for task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to use the AsyncEnumerator from https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator/

So i wrote the method exactly the same as their example however, my task isn't waiting at where is should be and just exits the programs.

I called the async fillData_async, and inside it have a parallelloop which runs my long tasks and is supposed to wait.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        ConcurrentBag<phoneData> Concurrent_PhoneNoList = new ConcurrentBag<phoneData>();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM numbers", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                phoneData temp = new phoneData();

                int phoneno = 0;

                if (int.TryParse(reader["number"].ToString(), out phoneno) == true)
                {
                    temp.phoneID = (int.Parse(reader["id"].ToString()));
                    temp.phoneNo = phoneno;
                }

                Concurrent_PhoneNoList.Add(temp);
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        string log += fillData_Async(Concurrent_PhoneNoList); // calls async here

        stopwatch.Stop(); // instantly continues without waiting
        TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        string.Format("{0}:{1}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalMinutes), ts.ToString("ss\\.ff"));

        log += "TotalTime: " + ts;

        Application.Exit();
    }
```

my async methods:

```
    private async Task<string> fillData_Async(ConcurrentBag<phoneData> phoneNolist)
    {
        string log = "Total Lines Retrieved From Database : " + phoneNolist.Count + "<br/>";

        int failures = 0;
        await phoneNolist.ParallelForEachAsync(async item =>
        {
            string returned_Data = await callWebServiceTask(item.phoneNo);

            if (returned_Data != "Failed")
            {
                item.Data = returned_Data;
            }
            else
            {
                //failedList1.Add(temp);
                failures++;
            }

        }, maxDegreeOfParalellism: 20);

        log += "Number of failures : " + failures;

        return log;
    }

    private Task<string> callWebServiceTask(int phoneNo)
    {
        string datareturned = myverylongtask(phoneNo); // public static string
        return Task.FromResult(datareturned);
    }
```

Comment: `string log += fillData_Async(Concurrent_PhoneNoList);`  I'm surprised that this even compiles without an `await` or call to the `.Result` property.

Comment: What appears to be happening is that `Form1_Load` is not waiting for the asynchronous method to finish, and then it calls Application.Exit()` while the method is still running.

Comment: yes it compiled, is it not supposed to be like this?

Comment: The reason why I'm surprised that it compiled is because the result of `fillData_Async(Concurrent_PhoneNoList)` is a `Task<string>`, and not a `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for `FillData_Async` to finish.  add `.Result` to the end, or `await` it

```
// note:  if you wait on a task like this from inside an async method,
// deadlocks might happen.
string log += fillData_Async(Concurrent_PhoneNoList).Result;
```

or

```
string log += await fillData_Async(Concurrent_PhoneNoList);
```

If you choose the `await`, approach, you'll have to make the calling method `Async`.

```
// async void should *only* be used for event handlers
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
```

Comment: Using `AsyncMethod().Result` is wrong approach for "really" asynchronous methods because of possible deadlocks. But it will work in OP case only because his code is clearly synchronous, there are no asynchronous methods. `await callWebServiceTask(item.phoneNo);` will be execute synchronously because it return already completed task.

Comment: Hi, just to update, after i changed some stuff, the .Result resulted in a dead lock, the Form1_Load async method worked